# tutrlesim_node fails due to incompatible Qt library

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ros, and currently following the beginners tutorials. I installed ros melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 and followed the instructions up to section 7 in http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes , where we need to activate the turtlesim node.

Running `$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`  I get the following:

````
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50905) with this library (version 0x50c01)
Aborted (core dumped)```


rqt and rqt-common-plugins run fine (if that's informative in any way).

I could not find any information on why this might be the case or how to fix it, I would appreciate any ideas!


---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331375/tutrlesim_node-fails-due-to-incompatible-qt-library/) by [EugVal](https://answers.ros.org/users/45054/eugval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-08-22


Post score: 0

---

### Original comments

**Comment by [cblakely](https://answers.ros.org/users/45251/cblakely/) on 2019-08-29**:\
Any luck with this?  I just ran into the same issue trying to run rviz2 for the first time.

**Comment by [EugVal](https://answers.ros.org/users/45054/eugval/) on 2019-09-23**:\
Unfortunately not, help with this would still be welcome!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to fix it by clearing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

My understanding is that turtlesim (and RViz) will use the default version of Qt installed with ubuntu (if they are installed through apt).  If you have another version of Qt somewhere in your system and point to it through the LD_LIBRARY_PATH they will then not work.

For reference, what helped me solve the issue: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1431

---

Originally posted by [EugVal](https://answers.ros.org/users/45054/eugval/) with karma: 16 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0